# Efficient calculation of polynomial coefficients from its roots

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, polynomial-math

I have the roots of a monic polynomial, i.e.

```
p(x) = (x-x_1)*...*(x-x_n)
```

and I need the coefficients a_n, ..., a_0 from

```
p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0.
```

Does anybody know a **computationally efficient** way of doing this? If anybody knows a C/C++ implementation, this would actually be the best. (I already had a look at GSL but it did not provide a function.)

Of course, I know how to to it mathematically. I know, that the coefficient `a_i` is the sum of all products of the subsets with `n-i` elements. But if I would do it the dumb way, this means to iterate across all subsets, I would need

```
sum^{n-1}_{k=1} ( k choose n) * (k-1)
```

multiplications and

```
sum^n_{k=0} ( k choose n) - n
```

additions. Hence both terms grow with `O(n!)`, which is too much computation to transform a list of `n` root into a list of `n` coefficients. I believe there must be some intelligent way to reuse most of the intermediate results, but I do not find one.

Comment: You can recursively build the polynomial by convolution. If this is a very large polynomial, at some point FFT will beat the O(n^2) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in `O(n^2)` very easily if you incrementally build your polynomial. Let's define:

```
p_k(x) = (x-x_1)*...*(x-x_k)
```

That is `p_k(x)` is the multiplication of the first `k` `(x-x_i)` of `p(x)`. We have:

```
p_1(x) = x-x_1
```

In other words the array of coefficients (`a`) would be (indices start from 0 and from left):

```
-x_1 1
```

Now assume we have the array of coefficients for `p_k(x)`:

```
a_0 a_1 a_2 ... a_k
```

(side note: `a_k` is 1). Now we want to calculate `p_k+1(x)`, which is (note that `k+1` is the index, and there is no summation by 1):

```
p_k+1(x) = p_k(x)*(x-x_k+1)
=> p_k+1(x) = x*p_k(x) - x_k+1*p_k(x)
```

Translating this to the array of coefficients, it means that the new coefficients are the previous ones shifted to the right (`x*p_k(x)`) minus the `k+1`th root multiplied by the same coefficients (`x_k+1*p_k(x)`):

```
           0   a_0 a_1 a_2 ... a_k-1 a_k
- x_k+1 * (a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_k)
-----------------------------------------
-x_k+1*a_0 (a_0-x_k+1*a_1) (a_1-x_k+1*a_2) (a_2-x_k+1*a_3) ... (a_k-x_k+1*a_k-1) a_k
```

(side note: and that is how `a_k` stays 1) There is your algorithm. Start from `p_1(x)` (or even `p_0(x) = 1`) and incrementally build the array of coefficients by the above formula for each root of the polynomial.

Comment: Umpf! If earth does not decide to swallow me up I volunteer to crawl under a rock and die. What ever, thank you. :-)

Comment: @user2690527, this is really just a simple for loop inside another. Just 3 or 4 lines of code. Don't give up!

Comment: I know. I believe you misinterpreted my 1st comment to your solution.My comment is meant to to say, shame on me. Such an easy solution and I did not come up with it by myself. Two master degrees (computer science and mathematics), but I spent my whole afternoon on that problem.

Comment: hahahaha, I understand now. Being a non-native speaker, sometimes some expressions turn out to have a different meaning than what I interpreted. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Just my *2 ¢*: shouldn't there be parenthesises around `(x_k+1)`? Multiplication has a higher precedence and multiplying by `1` doesn't change the value. SCNR.

Comment: No, that's `x` indexed by `k+1`. SO doesn't have support for tex math, so formatting math is hard. Technically, I could have written `x_(k+1)`, but there is already enough parentheses there that more would just look more confusing.

Comment: In the answer, I had also specified this: _note that `k+1` is the index, and there is no summation by 1_