# How to find out the sum of products of all combinations of first n natural numbers taken r at a time?n and r are both constants

Tags: math

Suppose n=10,r=3,then i want to find the sum of the products of numbers taken 3 at a time from 1 to 10 and all the combinations considered.There will be nCr possible products and i want their sum.

Comment: Can you provide an example? "products of numbers taken 3 at a time" is a bit vague.

Comment: This question is more suitable for math.stackexchange.com. Also, you should show some effort to solve the problem yourself; people won't want to help you if it looks like you just want them to give you the answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter suppose n=4 and r=2,then I want to find: [1.2+1.3+1.4+1.5+2.3+2.4+2.5+3.4+3.5+4.5] i.e. sum of all product combinations of first 5 natural numbers taken 2 at a time

Comment: @RobertDodier I tried this problem for hours by myself and when I couldn't solve only then I asked it here.

Comment: @RobertDodier I tried this problem for hours by myself and when I couldn't solve only then I asked it here.

Comment: OK. I believe you but it would help others if you put some note in the problem description about what you tried to do. After looking at this a little, it occurs to me to try to find a recurrence on n, that is, some formula like S(n + 1, m) = S(n, m) + (terms involving n and m) -- basically you just need to count up the new terms introduced each time you increase n. If you find a recurrence, you might be able to derive an explicit formula for S(n, m).

Comment: Your base case is S(m, m) which is m!. Note that S(m + 1, m) = m! + (m + 1)!/1 + (m + 1)!/2 + ... + (m + 1)!/m = m! times (1 + (m + 1) times (1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/m)) which you might simplify further if it matters. You could derive S(m + 2, m) etc, but I don't know if that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the degree 7 coefficient of

```
(x+1)(x+2)·…·(x+10)
```

You can compute all coefficients of that polynomial in O(n²) operations by adding one factor after the other.

---

For the computation of coefficients from roots see [How to efficiently find coefficients of a polynomial from its roots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067755/how-to-efficiently-find-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-from-its-roots), [Efficient calculation of polynomial coefficients from its roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236788/efficient-calculation-of-polynomial-coefficients-from-its-roots), [Find the coefficients of the polynomial given its roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594384/find-the-coefficients-of-the-polynomial-given-its-roots)

Comment: Can you show how to calculate that coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

A recurrence for `S(n, m)` where `S` is the sum you want is: `S(n + 1, m) = S(n, m) + (n + 1)*S(n, m - 1)`, with `S(n, 1) = n*(n + 1)/2` and `S(m, m) = m!`.

The term `(n + 1)*S(n, m - 1)` comes from the additional terms in the sum which are created by increasing `n` by 1: these terms are all the ones you get for `S(n, m - 1)` (i.e. take one fewer term in the product) and append `n + 1` to each one.

I don't know how to solve recurrences like that in general. In this case, I would build a table of terms `S(n, m)` which would look like a triangle. The bottom row would be for `S(n, 1)` which is `n*(n + 1)/2`. The diagonal would be `S(m, m)` which is `m!`. So you could try to guess a formula which gives general entries in the table and then add them all up.

A Python program to compute `S(n, m)` for specific values of `n` and `m` might look like:

```
import math
def S(n, m):
  if m == 1:
    return n*(n + 1)/2
  elif n == m:
    return math.factorial(m)
  else:
    return S(n - 1, m) + n*S(n - 1, m - 1)
```

which requires, I believe, approximately `m*n` unique calls to `S` (but there are many duplicates). Of course it's easy to write this in some other language.

For example, `S(10, 3) = 18150`.

EDIT: revised the estimated number of operations.